# Subclassing numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, subclass

I want to implement a subclass of `numpy.ndarray` that overrides the constructor with something like this:

```
class mymat(numpy.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, n, ...):
        ret = np.eye(n)

        # make some modifications to ret

        return ret
```

Unfortunately, the type of the object returned by this constructor is not `cls`, but rather `numpy.ndarray`.

Setting the class of `ret` with

```
ret.__class__ = cls # bombs: TypeError: __class__ assignment: only for heap types
```

won't work.

One possible solution would be something like

```
class mymat(numpy.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, n, ...):
        ret = super(mymat, cls).__new__(cls, (n, n))
        ret[:] = np.eye(n)

        # make some modifications to ret

        return ret
```

This is fine for small `n`, but I'd prefer to avoid the extra Python-side assignment when `n` is large.

Is there some other approach that would avoid this extra assignment, and still produce an object of class `mymat`?

Comment: Just making sure you're aware of http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html

Comment: I think you want view casting which should be explained in NPE's link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
class mymat(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, n):
        ret = np.eye(n)
        return ret.view(cls)
```